# Postgres replication not starting after configuration

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I am trying to install and create a PostgreSQL master-slave replication.

I have a problem after configured `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`; I can't restart Postgres with `systemctl restart postgresql-11.service`. It complained

```
AUTHENTICATING for org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units --Authentication is required to manage system services or units
```

I also cannot start Postgres with `pg_ctl`, it complains about

```
unrecognized configuration parameter checkpoint_segments in file postgresql.conf line 215
```

Is it wrong to set `checkpoint_segments=8` in `postgresql.conf`?

How can I restart Postgres?

My `postgresql.conf`:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 3
checkpoint_segments = 8
wal_keep_segments = 8
hot_standby = on
```

Comment: `checkpoint_segments` doesn't exist any more. The replacement is `max_wal_size`. The `AUTHENTICATING` error message is not from PostgreSQL - what did you do to get it? Did you create `recovery.conf`? If yes, with what parameters? Please read the documentation and follow the instructions there.

Comment: max_wal_size = 1G 
    min_wal_size = 80MB

 still can't start the postgres, authentication error.

Comment: That message has nothing to do with PostgreSQL. If that is the response to starting the service, perhaps it has to do with your service file. You'll have to share more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you please check if you have max_wal_size = 1**G** or max_wal_size = 1**GB** in conf file.
in-case it is 1G, you will not be able to start the service. it should be **GB**

Comment: I rebuilt the new data in local instead of shared drive and it works fine and import to slaveserver successful. After modified the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf from slaveserver, can't start psql. Work around with new setting from master today and all are dead.  On master complained about postmaster.pid does not existed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post it as an at least partial answer, since this is the cause of the `unrecognized configuration parameter` error.

According to [Laurenz's answer](/users/6464308), parameter `checkpoint_segments` doesn't exist anymore. The replacement is `max_wal_size`.

Also, confirming what Laurenz said up there, "AUTHENTICATING" line is not related to Postgres. With all credits to them, you should search for problems in Linux services.